# What should be the file folder structure in Codeigniter with Angularjs

Tags: php, css, angularjs, codeigniter, fonts

I have just started to work on an app in Codeigniter with AngularJS. I want to use font-awesome offline but can't make it to work.
I suspect the file folder structure of my application which is:

```
CI-AJS-APP
 -app
 -application
 -assets
  -css
  -font-awesome
   -font-awesome.css
   -font
  -js
 -system
 ...
```

Now in my **font-awesome.css** file I have a reference to the **fonts** folder as:

```
@font-face {

    font-family: "FontAwesome";
    src: url('font/fontawesome-webfont.eot');
    src: url('font/fontawesome-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('eot'),
    url('font/fontawesome-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
    url('font/fontawesome-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'),
    url('font/fontawesome-webfont.svg#FontAwesome')
    format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;

          }
```

In my application header I have included the **font-awesome.css** file as:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo base_url();?>assets/
font-awesome/font-awesome.css">
```

I have not fully integrated AngularJS in CI however just for a page or two on which I want to show the font-awesome icons.

Any kind of help will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Well I have found that file structure is alright. The reason for the problem was that I was using **ng-class** the wrong way.

This is what I was doing...

```
ng-class="{{fa fa-sort-asc}}"
```

But I found that the correct way to achieve this is...

```
ng-class="{{'fa fa-sort-asc'}}"
```

**Notice the missing single quotes with the classname** in the former code.

So, this mistake was not displaying the font-awesome icon at all in the browser.

Hope will be helpful to some out there :-).